# Digital sigining - distributed environment - seperate hashing and signing

Tags: cryptography, hash, digital-signature

I need to digitally sign a data packet of size 50 MB in a distributed environment. Signing takes place at the central server and the clients will be sending the data packets to the central server. I wanted to avoid the bottlenecks in the network by sending huge packets of data.

My question is

1. Can i generate the Hash at the client end and just send the hash to the central server for signing?
2. Is there any security flaws in this approach?

Thanks

Comment: What threats are you trying to protect against?

Comment: My requirement is to implement digital signing for financial transaction data from one bank before sending it to the other bank which will verify the same. So i should make sure that my implementation is secure enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign the hash received from the client, yet there's a security problem here -- you need to find a way to ensure that the hash is derived from the data that is authorized to be hashed. Imagine the situation where your server uses corporate certificate to sign executables that your dev.team compiles. Now a hacker creates a troyan and finds a way to send signing request (by passing only the hash) to your server. And he gets a troyan, signed using your company certificate. This is less real for external attacks, but not for internal ones.

Comment: It's correct that everything depends on the integrity of the client. But thats valid regardless of sending a hash or the complete content.

Comment: @mtraut not exactly. If it's 50Mb-large PDF document to be signed (on the server), then the server can check certain parameters of PDF document (or even modify it by putting a watermark, for example). If it's an XML file, the server can check whether the XML follows the acceptable structure. But none of this is possible with having just a hash.

Comment: That's right. But he can do only formal checks. He does not know if 10.00$ or 10,000,000.00$ is valid.

Comment: @mtraut it depends, again. For example, the system can be configured to automatically sign only documents for under $10K (otherwise manual verification is required). In almost any case, having the data is better than having just a hash.

Comment: @eugene, I've heard of computers that manage to create very fast requests with only 1.00$ that sum up right quickly. To be honest now, you're from a security company. You'd never accept (and SOX and whoever reviews these processes won't either) a scheme that depends on server heuristics where client and transport security is asked for. For sure one can make "additional" checks - but if you're sure about the request integrity you would not do any checks and if you can't be sure because of protocol defects you would not sign it.

Comment: @mtraut in $1 case did you consider the check for duplicate documents? :) In any case, such checks are very specific to the task and any generic check can be claimed not effective or flawed, and this would be so for *generic* one. However, in particular scenarios that have their own constraints, automated checks of some kind can be possible. Also it's a big mistake to trust the data because you trust it's source. I'd say it is more dangerous than trust the data based on thorough automated checking.

Answer (score 2):

Blindly signing a hash seems like a risky proposal.  There are a few questions that seem pertinent in this situation:

- Are the clients "trusted"?
- Is the communications channel trusted?
- Does the server perform any verification of the data that it receives and signs?

The last one may be the most critical. If the server does not verify the data and just blindly signs it, then it probably is not really any different than blindly signing a hash.  Either process allows anyone to get any piece of data signed.

Comment: ..and if the server isn't performing any validation of the data, you might as well just eliminate the central server entirely and hand the signing key out to the clients.

Comment: Thanks, your questions summarised the factors which i should be considering.